# Cant declare instance variable in C++ MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

Right now, im doing this Tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20187/The-Ultimate-Grid-Beginner-s-Guide
Please have a short look at it so you understand my problem.

At the part where I must declare an Instance of the MyCug grid class, ive got a problem. Ive included the Header files in my Class + App classes. But when I want to declare the Instance, there is an error: error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed
Error on the line where i want to declare it:

```
class CClassView : public CDockablePane { public:   
MyCug m_grid;
```

If i declare it in the .cpp file, it works. But its not public.
Are there any options for a solution? I hope you understand my problem

Here is some Code:

```
#include "ViewTree.h"
class CClassToolBar : public CMFCToolBar
{
virtual void OnUpdateCmdUI(CFrameWnd* /*pTarget*/, BOOL bDisableIfNoHndler)
{
    CMFCToolBar::OnUpdateCmdUI((CFrameWnd*) GetOwner(), bDisableIfNoHndler);
}

virtual BOOL AllowShowOnList() const { return FALSE; }
};

class CClassView : public CDockablePane
{
public: 
MyCug m_grid;
```

Comment: please show the top of the .h file. The error message means that the compiler doesn't know what `MyCug` should be. Most probable cause is that you *didn't* include the header containing `MyCug` before that.

Comment: @nyarlathotep Just to clarify the problem is that the OP didn't include the mycug.h file in the header file containing CClassView. Sounds like he did include it in the cpp file.

Comment: Show more code please.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to include the header for MyCug

Another option is to forward declare MyCug and then declare it as a pointer

```
class MyCug;

class CClassView : public CDockablePane
{
public:
  MyCug* m_grid;
...
}
```

you must then instantiate the pointer in your constructor for instance

```
m_grid = new MyCug;
```

and delete in your destructor

```
delete m_grid;
```

or in some other suitable place.

alt. declare `m_grid` as a `unique_ptr`

```
class MyCug;

class CClassView : public CDockablePane
{
public:
  std::unique_ptr<MyCug*> m_grid;
...
}
```

then it is enough to instantiate it in the constructor

```
m_grid.reset(new MyCug);
```